# Ограничить время выполнения file_get_contents()

Tags: php, файлы

Как ограничить время выполнения file_get_contents()? Выполняется скрипт, если не загрузился файл за n секунд идем дальше отменив загрузку, как такое осуществить?

Comment: А вы реально читаете файл или всё-таки загружаете что-то по HTTP?

Comment: @ Zhukov Roman По HTTP

Comment: А почему вы в вопросе говорите про файл?

Comment: @ Zhukov Roman По тому что в названии функции есть слово file )  (обертка над данными, и функция видит как файл- думал я- не знаю внутренней механики) Если принципиально данные воспринимаются функцией не как файл, то напишите как исправить и дайте ответ. За ранее благодарен.

Comment: Я сразу использую Guzzle, меньше потом переписывать. В первом комментарии к этой функции в оф. доке всё есть.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman переписал почти уже в curl-е . Думал, что есть какое то простое решение- вроде function(file_get_contents(...),5(секунд)) погуглил-не нашел- решил поинтересоваться у спецов- теперь задача решена, остался академический интерес.

Comment: В первом комментарии к функции `file_get_contents()` всё есть, вы читали его? :)

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Выставляем в опциях контекста 'timeout' => $n ?

Comment: да, совершенно верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?php
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'timeout' => $n,   // Время в секундах
    )
)
);
file_get_contents("http://str.com/", 0, $ctx);
```